# Corona SDK event phase

Tags: lua, coronasdk

```
function drag(event)
if event.phase == "began" then
    firstx, firsty = event.x, event.y
end

if event.phase == "ended" then
    if firsty<event.y then
        local otherx, othery = event.x, event.y
        local x=(otherx-firstx)*4
        local y=(othery-firsty)*4
        shoot(x,y)
    end
end
end
```

Problem with the event.phase?

The program gets an error when it compares firsty with event.y.

error: Attempt to compare nil with number

The weird part is that it works perfectly if I only let the program load for a few seconds..

Comment: `firsty` is not being set to anything other than `nil` before it is compared in that case, or `event.y` is `nil` sometimes and overwrites `firsty`.

Comment: hmm.. firsty seems to be the one who is nil, but how can it be nil if it was declared when the event.phase begun (when I touch the screen)

Comment: Where is `firsty` declared? It isn't used anywhere else in the program, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going on with `firsty` without seeing more of your code, but how about this instead? I think it'll be a more robust fix to your problem.

```
function drag(event)
    if event.phase == "ended" then
        if event.yStart < event.y then
            local y = (event.y - event.yStart) * 4
            local x = (event.x - event.xStart) * 4
            shoot(x, y)
        end
    end
end
```

You can make use of [x & yStart](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/touch/yStart.html) to get the initial co-ordinates for the event instead of trying to save it yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that event.yStart existed.

Comment: You're welcome. If this has solved your problem, please let others know by ticking the green checkmark by the answer.